# Convert few columns to rows in the select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| ID |  ItemName | OldValue | newValue |  OrderId  | sequenceNo
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 |  Item1   |   1     | 1.5     |  SO2   |   6
| 2 |  Item2   |   4     | 6       |  SO2   |   4
| 3 |  Item3   |   3     | 68      |  SO2    |  9 
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have to write a query where OldValue column data should come as new rows like example below

```
ItemName | allValues   |OrderId  | sequenceNo
----------------------------------------------
Item1   |   1          |  SO2   |   0
Item2   |   4          |  SO2   |   0
Item3   |   3          |  SO2   |   0
Item1   |   1.5        |  SO2   |   6
Item2   |   6          |  SO2   |   4
Item3   |   68         |  SO2   |   9
-----------------------------------------------
```

I did this using a UNION where I have written

```
select itemName , oldValue as allValues , OrderId from Orderdetails
UNION
select itemName , newValue as allValues , OrderId from Orderdetails
```

Is there a better way to write this without UNION?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a VALUES clause to do the UNPIVOT

```
select t.itemname,
       u.allvalues,
       t.orderid,
       u.sequenceno
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
     values (oldvalue, 0), (newvalue, t.sequenceno)
  ) as u(allvalues, sequenceno)
order by t.itemname;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. It works exactly as expected. If you dont mind, I have editted the question and added a new column named sequenceId. For all the rows with oldValue should get the sequenceId as 0. What can I do in the above query to achieve that?

Comment: Right now sequence Id is getting repeated for both the rows.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: see my edit. In the future please include all relevant details in your question right from the start.

Comment: Thanks so much. Will keep that in mind from next time.